# 8 port router or 3 port router with 5 port switch

Tags: router, ethernet, switch

I just recently got my condo wired with 6 Ethernet ports.

I was wondering is there any performance difference if I were to get either just an 8 port router and just connect everything to it vs if I got a 3 port router with a 5 Port Switch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An 8 port router is just a router with a built-in switch, so there is no difference between the two solutions, speed-wise.

A wireless router (which is the norm these days for a consumer device sold as a "router") is typically 3 devices built into the same box:

- a router
- a switch
- a wireless access point

**Benefits of an 8 port router is:**

- Everything is in one box, so it takes up less space.
- You only need to provide one device with power
- If the router has advanced features (VLAN, VPN, DMZ etc.) then it will be configurable on all ports

**Benefits of seperate router and switch:**

- The router is usually cheaper with less ports
- It's easier to upgrade the router at a later time, as you're not required to get a new one with as many (8 in this case) ports
- You can place the router and switch in seperate places (this might not be a benefit in your case depending on where your ethernet ports are and where your internet is comming in)
- You can get a PoE (Power over Ethernet) switch if needed. PoE is typically used for low-power devices like IP cameras and some wireless access points

Comment: "An 8 port router is just a router with a built-in switch, so there is no difference between the two solutions, speed-wise." Unless the router is actually processing the traffic, in which case a switch would probably be faster.